# magento 1.9 remove checkbox in terms and condition

Tags: magento-1.9

is it possible to remove check box in terms and conditions 
i am not developer just check point which you mention and solved me problem.

please see the screen shot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can enable/disable that in System `Configuration > Sales > Checkout > Checkout Options > Enable Terms and Conditions`